# Handling bulk URLs in MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm implementing a CRUD system on MEAN stack that can create, edit and delete courses. I wanted to know how to manage URLs for every course that I create. I'm using routeprovider. Will I have to write code that looks like this - ?

```
 $routeProvider 
        .when('/courses/course1', 
            {
                templateUrl: '/partials/course1',
                controller: 'CourseCtrl1'
            }
         )
        .when('/courses/course2', 
            {
                templateUrl: '/partials/course2',
                controller: 'CourseCtrl2'
            }
         )
        .when('/courses/course3', 
            {
                templateUrl: '/partials/course3',
                controller: 'CourseCtrl3'
            }
        )
        ...
```

Or is there some library/factory that can help me in making this simpler?

Since I plan to have more than 100 courses with each course having it's own unique URL, the above method doesn't seem to be feasible. 
I have 2 questions

1. How do I handle URLs for multiple courses without having to write
   hundreds of lines of repeating code in routeprovider?
2. Since I plan
   to make this CRUD system a small CMS kind of setup, is it possible
   to automatically generate URLs when adding a new course everytime (like how
   Drupal and Wordpress manage it)?

I am struggling a lot with this problem. I hope I've provided enough details to answer the question or else please let me know so that I can provide more details. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?:

```
.when('/courses', 
        {
            templateUrl: '/partials/coursesList',
            controller: 'CoursesListCtrl'
        }
     )
    .when('/courses/:courseNumber', 
        {
            templateUrl: '/partials/singleCourse',
            controller: 'SingleCourseCtrl'
        }
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with Node.js and express, the Express.js way to do it:

Create router and config it

```
var CoursesListCtrl = require('./CoursesListCtrl');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/courses', CoursesListCtrl.getAll);
router.get('/course/:id', CoursesListCtrl.getById);
```

Create app, register router as middleware and start listening

```
var app = express();
app.use(router);
app.listen(3000); // 3000 is the port you are listening to
```

CoursesListCtrl could look something like

```
module.exports = {
    getAll: function(req, res){
        /** Get all courses from db */
        res.status(200).send(courses);
    },
    getById: function(req, res){
        var courseId = req.params['id'];
        /** Get course from db by id */
        res.status(200).send(course);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using is the old thing. Angular now provides $stateProvider service using which you can create the states which give a easier way to generate the states for each url and also switching between states is easier as you dont need to remember the complete url every time. You need to add **angular-ui-router** library.

```
var app  =  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '/login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController',
  })
  .state('reset', {
    url: '/reset-password',
    templateUrl: '/login/reset.html',
    controller: 'resetController',     
  })

})
```

And then in controllers, you can easily switch the state using *$state* service like this :

```
app.controller('resetController',['$state',function($state) {
    $state.go("login");    
  }   
]);
```